# Forums with lot of hand history analysis by other players

Tags: resources

Can you give me some links please to forums with lot of hands history analized by other players, like this one: [link](http://www.pokerstrategy.com/forum/board.php?boardid=1387&daysprune=1000&sortfield=lastposttime&sortorder=DESC&page=1)

I've come across several forums with same purpose but there seems to be too small community or too few topics on them.

Comment: Nice question I was wondering about this just the other day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Two Plus Two](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/) would be the most popular. I'm not sure how active they are now, by [Liquid Poker](http://www.liquidpoker.net/poker-forum) was decently big as well. I was also very, very active on the Full Tilt Poker forums before they went down (they may come back up now that the site is running again though).

The training sites (in addition to having awesome videos) also tend to have forums (though they may be members only):

- [Deuces Cracked](http://www.deucescracked.com/forums)
- [Card Runners (registration required)](http://www.cardrunners.com/cr_forums/forum.php)
- [Blue Fire Poker (too few topics compared to others)](http://www.bluefirepoker.com/forums)
- [Leggo Poker (even smaller then previous)](http://www.leggopoker.com/forums/)
- [Grinderschool (members-only, small stakes focus)](http://www.grinderschool.com/phpBB3/)

Comment: thanks, for your answer, it really saved me hours of googling

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

you can also check out the new site of Phil Galfond [Run it once](http://www.runitonce.com/) which features really good content

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Now there are many poker rooms or poker forums to improve your poker skills. Than those days haha. https://holdemgallery.com It contains a lot of content about poker. For example, playing poker or how to play poker etc.

Comment: Can the writer disclose if they have an affiliation with the linked site? They have posted it at least twice, thanks.